# Python requests not able to use ports?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, python-requests

I have an http server on a port X. Now i tried to use request.get("host:X") to get a website.
I get a status code 400.
After that I tried urllib2.open("host:X") and it worked.

Is there a special parameter in Requests to use ports? I didnt find any. Or does it simply not work?

Comment: I just got `200` from `r"http://www.google.com:80"`, and a timeout on a non-80 port to the same url, so it seems like it does work. Make sure you're prefixing the url with `"http://"`

Comment: `requests` supports other ports *just fine*. The fact that you got a response code *at all* shows that it worked, but that the *server* decided to respond differently (based on the contents of the request, including the headers). This is an issue with the server, *not with `requests`*.

Comment: @TankorSmash: Omitting the `http://` scheme part leads to an exception, not a response code.

Comment: @TankorSmash it is prefixed with http, still no use. The weird thing is that it works with urllib but not with requests. I always get 400 with requests.

Comment: @BugHead Your next step should probably be to examine the request headers actually sent to the server in both cases and see where they differ.

Comment: I tried `requests.post("http://host/test:8000")` and got a 404. I then remembered that I should be using `requests.post("http://host:8000/test")` and everything worked fine!